# Oracle query to update table A to set A.ID to B.ID, but where B.Name = C.Name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables, Table A, Table B, and Table C.

Here is the psuedo code:

```
update A
set A.id = B.id
where B.name = C.name
```

How can I write something like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+update+with+join

Comment: You've given us no information as to how tables A, B, and C relate--so there is no way we can even start to give you help.

Comment: I want to update the IDs in A to match the IDs in B.

Comment: C is the table that has names for which I want the IDs in A to match IDs in B.  C and B have exact same names, so I want to set the names equal to each other.

Comment: since the names appear only once in both C and B (B when using distinct)

Comment: You need to explain how A relates to C.  What does the name in table C (or any other field) have to do with any record in table A